# model to predict value of an observation vs its quantile in a population

Tags: regression, predictive-models, quantiles

I have 1 million customers, and I'm interested in predicting the revenue generated by each of the them in the following month. Consider two models:

- Model A: predict the actual revenue (e.g. in dollars) generated by a given customer
- Model B: predict the quantile that the revenue from the given customer falls in among all the customers. For e.g.

> revenue from customer John will fall in the 92nd percentile

or equivalently

> customer John will generate more revenue than 92% of his peers

My preference is for Model B as it outputs a "normalized" quantity that'd be robust to macroeconomic changes such as inflation. However, I was wondering about the pros/cons of doing so. What is this modeling approach called and is it common?

(Please note that this is unrelated to [Quantile Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Unclear questions according to the Community Bot](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6341/1352)

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the predictions?

Comment: IMO depends, for example, if you have in the features also something like "avg_spending" or something like this, that feature is also correlated to inflation, so maybe you want to have the actual value as output, where instead the quantile in that case would not be adjusted to inflation, thus leading to over/underestimates

Comment: also, consider that the target will have different distributions, therefore it's going to be a bit though to compare them, since you are doing regression, and usually the loss is used to compare models

Comment: Is there a big difference? We can run model A, and then get B by taking the percentile for John’s predicted value in the list of observations; or we can run model B, and then get A by taking the value for John’s predicted percentile from the list of observations.